# I am getting a error while installing turtle in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm, python-turtle

I am trying to install turtle package in pycharm, but while installing i got this error:

```
Collecting turtle
  Using cached turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Ptr\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\turtle\setup.py", line 40
        except ValueError, ve:
        except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
```

I don't know what to do, help  me please.

Answer (score 2):

`pip` installs [`turtle` 0.0.2](https://pypi.org/project/turtle/0.0.2/) from PyPI. Released in 2009. The code is obviously Python2-only.

You don't need to install `turtle` — it's [a module from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) since at least Python 2.6. Just import it and use.

Comment: This should be considered as the answer.